# When does LIMIT 1 return more than one row?

Tags: mysql

I have a correlated subquery in an update that used to work just fine (last year it worked; this year I made some small changes to the schema and the data are different). Now it fails with "Subquery returns more than 1 row" error.

The query is this:

```
update mytable as q
set p_ID = (
  select ap.pID
    from aptable as ap
    where ap.ID = q.ID
      and ap.txnDate is not NULL
      order by ap.txnDate
      limit 1 offset 2
   )
```

Weird, eh?

To find where it returns more than one row - which should be impossible, I prepared the query with the addition of "where ap.ID = ?" and ran the query in a loop for each valid ID value. Guess what - it worked all the way through.

Any ideas of what's going on here?

Comment: What's the error if the subquery returns no results?  Could it just be a bad error message?

Comment: Which version of MySQL? [This bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=20519) sounds relevant, but was fixed in 5.0.25.

Comment: @knabar - then I would have seen that case when I did it an ID at a time. It ran to completion successfully. Thanks for the idea, though.

Comment: Ahah! @ruakh, you are right. I'm using 5.0.22. Have to talk with the sysadmin. :-)

Comment: @DMac: In that case I'll post it as an answer, just to make it "formal". :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing it's due to [Bug #20519: "'Subquery returns more that 1 row' error with 'limit x, 1'"](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=20519), which was fixed in MySQL 5.0.25.

Comment: What - you've memorized all the version's release notes? :-) Thanks - nice work.